# Why is WordPress transforming my post's title differently than a regular string?

Tags: php, wordpress, string, replace

In WordPress, entitled `My Town - Charleston, SC`

In PHP 7.2, I would like to take this title and turn it into `charleston,-sc`

To do this, I'm using `str_replace`, `strtolower`, and `trim`.

```
$title = trim(str_replace('my town -', '', strtolower(get_the_title())));
$locationTag = str_replace(' ', '-', $title);
```

This works in regular PHP if I replace `get_the_title` with the string itself, but when I use the code on a WordPress template page, it does not replace `my town -` with a blank. Instead it only replaces spaces with dashes and makes everything lowercase.

Why is this happening? Does WordPress do some weird order of operations here to optimize stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because for some reason `get_the_title` function converts '-' into '–'. I am not sure if you can see it clearly but the second dash is a bit wider.

I recreated the problem in my local environment and found this weird behavior.

```
var_dump( get_the_title() ); echo '<br>';
var_dump( $post->post_title ); echo '<br>';
var_dump( "My Town - Charleston, SC" ); echo '<br>';
```

You can see it clearly here in this screenshot-

[image: Different dashes-]

Comment: Arghh! WordPress and it's annoying need to convert things unnecessarily. So I need to use `get_post()->post_title` instead? That's so dumb. Thank you for helping me figure this out